# Is this the correct way of moving MySQL data directory, (on Centos)?

Tags: mysql, centos

I need to move my data directory to a bigger drive on the same server.

```
# stop mysql
/etc/init.d/mysql stop

# copy the data over
cp -R -p /var/lib/mysql /home/mysql

#edit my.cnf
# and add a 'datadir' section with the new path.

#restart mysql
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

The copying of the data will take ages, (I suspect), but at least it will be safe.

I might also want to add a temp directory somewhere.

Do I need to do anything else to move the data.

Will I need to rebuild indexes or something else?

Comment: Important - check the user and permissions - the datadir should be owned by the `mysql` user and group and entire path has to be accessible by that user (should not be a problem with `/home`) and then check if you are running `apparmor` or `selinux` and if it will allow mysql to access that directory. No need to rebuild anything if it starts.

Comment: Although unlikely but mind that innodb specific parameters `innodb_log_group_home_dir` and `innodb_data_home_dir` can have different values than `datadir`. Make sure these are not set or repointed too. Also in case you have replication then check `log-bin` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would keep that folder, and instead of changing it you'd either mount another folder or partition on it prior to starting mysql, or create a symlink elsewhere (there are answers for doing this [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/442218/remounting-mysql-under-a-new-mount-point) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743245/how-to-move-a-mysql-database-to-another-mount-point)).

You won't need to rebuild anything for moving your files, but it is a good idea to always make a backup before attempting something like this that may damage your data if anything goes wrong.